# Storing Categories in a Database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

If some object can be a `video, audio,` or `story` is it better to have a separate table for each category or is it OK to have a `"type"` field that contains lots and lots of `"audio"`, `"video"` and `"story"` entries?

1) ASSUME that each object can only be of one type

2) ASSUME that each object can be of multiple types (In this case it seems its best to define an ObjectType table that stores the relations between objects and types right?)

(I am using a relational database)

Thanks!

Comment: try making a sample for each and test, along the way you will find challenges, and u will get help here

Comment: Can an item be in more than one category?  A video can also be a story, can it not?

Comment: @Will A Good Point...i'll edit the question to reflect this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggested schemas below.  By using IDs rather than strings you lessen the amount of storage, and effort required by the database engine when joining.  You also make it much easier to rename a category - rather than having to update umpteen rows where category is used, you update the one CATEGORY row.

With just one category per item:

```
ITEM:
ID
CATEGORYID
...

CATEGORY:
ID
NAME
...
```

With multiple categories per item:

```
ITEM:
ID
...

CATEGORY:
ID
NAME
...

ITEMCATEGORY:
ITEMID
CATEGORYID
```

Comment: Thanks this confirms what I thought in the second category. Thanks for pointing out the difficulty in changing the name of the category without using IDs

Comment: My pleasure, AC - it'll pay dividends in the long run if you also put foreign keys in place.

Comment: The important thing is *not* the "effort" (unless this can be *proven* to be an issue), but rather ensuring the consistency and usability of the underlying relational model -- an this is *not* possible without FK's (use of surrogate PK's aside).

Comment: @pst - agreed, storage + effort take a back seat to the main issue of ease of maintenance.